# Let $|c|<1$, the prove that $n^\frac{2}{5}c^n \rightarrow 0 \: \text{as} \: n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $|c|<1$, the prove that $n^\frac{2}{5}c^n \rightarrow 0  \: \text{as} \: n \rightarrow \infty$.

I know how to do this using $|c|^n \leq \frac{1}{1+nd} \leq \frac{1}{nd},\: \text{where} \: d>0$ and the comparison lemma. However, I have a final coming up and I cannot just state the above inequality without proving it. My question is: is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: What is $ d $? ${} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$n^{2/5}c^n=\left[(n^{1/n})^{2/5}\cdot c\right]^n$$ If $n\to\infty \implies n^{1/n}\to 1$, then

$$n^{2/5}c^n=\left[(n^{1/n})^{2/5}\cdot c\right]^n\equiv c^n$$

Comment: What does $\equiv$ mean?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo quiero dar a entender que el límite es semejante o que es equivalente al límite de $c^n$ cuando $n$ tiende a infinito, no se que simbolo será más adecuado.

Comment: Did you mean $\left(n^{1/n}\right)^ {2/5}$?

Comment: @dafinguzman yes thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$u_n=n^{\frac{2}{5}}c^n \implies \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(n+1)^{\frac{2}{5}}c^{n+1}}{n^{\frac{2}{5}}c^n}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{2}{5}}c=c<1$

$$\boxed{\therefore\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider $n^{\alpha}c^{n}$. Note that $\partial_{n}c^{n}=c^{n}\ln c$
and $\partial_{n}n^{\alpha}=\alpha n^{\alpha-1}$.